# How to create a simple connection table in Java?

Tags: java, spring, h2, lombok

I am trying to set up a very simple database with two tables in Java and connect them using a specific connection table.

1st table Student consists of id, first_name and last_name.

2nd table Course consists of id and name.

The connection table called Enrollment should have course_id and student_id that originate from 1st and 2nd tables.

My problem is I don't know how to map the IDs when extending Spring Data JPA's AbstractPersistable, which has an auto-increment primary key field in it.

My code:

Student:

```
// Package
// Imports

@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Student extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

}
```

Course:

```
// Package
// Imports

@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Course extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String name;

}
```

I have tried different usages of @ManyToMany annotation but since the primary key ID is handled by AbstractPersistable, I have failed to map the 'invisible' IDs for the connection table.

I also know that the connection table and its columns can be named with @Column, @JoinColumn and @JoinTable. I haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i would try something like this ...

```
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Student extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

     @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "enrollment",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
     private List<Course> courses;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Course extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private List<Student> students;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is actually very similar to the one I eventually came up with so I will accept this.